# Laravel homestead: Unknown database 'projectadmin_db'

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, homestead

I am new to laravel. I use homestead for development. I have two database connection

database.php

```
'cust_main_db'   =>  [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'project_db',
        'username'  => 'homestead',
        'password'  => 'secret',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
    'admin_main_db'   =>  [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'projectadmin_db',
        'username'  => 'homestead',
        'password'  => 'secret',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

Homestead.yaml

```
databases:
    - homestead
```

In my local mysql has both databases `project_db` and `projectadmin_db`

When I run the project `http://homestead.app:8000/` it shows `SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'projectadmin_db'`

What I have missed here? Correct me if anything wrong.

Answer (score 2):

When you run your app in Homestead, it looks for databases in Homestead and not your actual localhost. You can connect to Homestead's MySQL through `127.0.0.1:33060`.

Comment: Homestead database 33060 mapped with default 3306 right?

Comment: Yeah your app config should be the default 3306.  What I meant was that if you use Sequel Pro, Navicat or a similar app, you should specify port as 33060 to connect Homestead MySQL instead of your local MySQL which is at 3306.

Comment: In my case this results in "connection failed!"

Answer (score 0):

On models that use `projectadmin_db` database, you need to add

```
protected $connection = 'admin_main_db';
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you use the default Homestead port 33060 , when you are creating your databases ,

i.e: you created your databases on the guest vm not on the host machine.